# How to locate the center of the peaks of a mesh 3d plot automatically?

Tags: matlab, signals, digital

I have been working on the 3d plots for a while in matlab. I have plotted three matrices on the mesh plot with a 40 by 40 grid and I could see peaks manually and locate the peaks manually but I'm not able to find a method to locate the peaks automatically using logic of the 40 by 40 1600 point grid where we can compare each vertice and see which one has the maximum number of points and thus automatically get the vertices. If someone could help me how to read the data of the plot and thus define a logic to compare the vertices.

Answer (score 0):

I argue that you are trying to find local maxima (and/or minima) in your matrix.
In this case, there is a function in the Cumputer Vision toolbox if you have it. If don't, you can simply create a function that iterates over elements of your matrix and takes a portion of it (let's say, 3x3, but could be also 5x5 or more). Then you check if the central element is the biggest of that small matrix, and if it is you add the coordinates (row and col indexes) in a vector.
You can also give the size of the sub-matrix as a parameter, to define how sensitive is your function to small peaks.

Comment: well its not exactly the local maxima but ya you could say that either.i created a matrix of 40x40 so u want me to develop a logic to iterate over elements of the matrix and check for small portions of that matrix rite.wt i dont undertand is while u are taking a matrix u would get the column n row funtions,how would you get the coordinates.i m sorry if this is silly questions i m new to matlab could you please tell me how?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?